# Meaning of "get on someome" in context

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

I've come across it in the 7th episode of the 6th season of *the Walking Dead*. Here is the context:

> Glen: The herd broke
> through the walls?
>
> Enid: What herd?
>
> Glen: The walkers.
>
> They broke out of the quarry early.
>
> We **got on them**, but that sound, the air horn,
>
> what was that?

Sidenote: in one of the previous episodes they tried to draw zombies away from the place place the are staying in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd understand this as "we got near them and handled the situation".

We can use "get on something" to mean "start work to do something"

> Can you clean the toilets?

> Sure, I'll get on that right away.

Here the meaning seems to be similar.  Glen is saying that the walkers broke out of the quarry, but he dealt with the situation (perhaps by herding them back into the quarry?)